# CMAKE: automatically add dependencies of dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-build

I am trying to migrate a [boost-build](http://www.boost.org/build/) build system to cmake.

One of the features boost-build has is automatically linking dependencies of dependencies.

For example:

**boost-build:**

I'm building an executable `app`. It depends on `lib2`

```
exe app
:   [ glob *.cpp ]
    /proj/lib2//lib2
;
```

In turn, `lib2` depends on `lib1`

```
lib lib2
:   [ glob *.cpp ]
    /proj/lib1//lib1
;
```

and `lib1` has no dependencies

```
lib lib1
:    [ glob *.cpp ]
;
```

Both `lib1` and `lib2` are static libs.

boost-build will automatically add `lib1.a` to the linker line for `app` because it knows that `lib2.a` depends on `lib1.a`

**cmake:**

**Explicitly** stating both `lib1` and `lib2` in the `target_link_libraries` directive works:

lib1:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

lib2:

```
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

app:

```
add_executable(app ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(app lib1 lib2)
```

As the number of libraries grows this becomes cumbersome.

```
target_link_libraries(app lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 lib5 lib6 lib7 lib8 lib9 ... libN)
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to specify that `lib2` depends on `lib1`
- Is there a way to tell `app` to pull in `lib2` **and whatever `lib2` depends on?**

Comment: you might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake

Comment: @TomaszLewowski this one is a far better one: [setting-dependencies-between-libraries-cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970071/setting-dependencies-between-libraries-cmake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as adding `target_link_libraries` to `lib2`

lib1:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

lib2:

```
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1)
```

app:

```
add_executable(app ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(app lib2)
```

Comment: Note that this approach also saves you from the headache of order-dependency with certain linker toolchains. `gcc`'s linker for instance is very picky about this and will refuse to link if you don't order the arguments in a flattened list of static libraries correctly. By modeling the library dependencies like here, CMake is able to figure all of that out for you.